# Sonarqube can't be started in Ubuntu

Tags: sonarqube

When I tried to start the sonarqube it gives me following errors.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.08.19 17:30:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.08.19 17:30:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.08.19 17:30:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.08.19 17:30:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.08.19 17:30:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.08.19 17:30:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.08.19 17:30:41 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.08.19 17:30:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.08.19 17:30:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I can't find any solution for this problem and I really need some help to run sonarqube. I might have done something wrong, but I've followed sonarqube documentation for installation.

And this is the es.log file

```
Server VM/11.0.4/11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3]
2019.08.20 20:38:29 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [mapper-extras]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [repository-url]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2019.08.20 20:38:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2019.08.20 20:38:34 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.s.Settings] [http.enabled] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
2019.08.20 20:38:36 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
2019.08.20 20:38:36 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2019.08.20 20:38:36 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
2019.08.20 20:38:37 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2019.08.20 20:38:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `es.log` please?

Comment: @mc1arke es.log file is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is withing the sonar.service file which should be stayed in `/etc/systemd/system.sonar.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=sonarqube
Group=sonarqube
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/bin/nohup /opt/java/bin/java -Xms32m -Xmx32m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /opt/sonarqube/lib/sonar-application-7.4.jar
StandardOutput=syslog
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNPROC=8192
TimeoutStartSec=5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You have to define the file limit on the service

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is not starting, see the logs :

> 2019.08.20 20:38:37 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] node validation exception
>   [1] bootstrap checks failed
>   [1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]

And here is what they say in [their doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html):

> Elasticsearch uses a lot of file descriptors or file handles. Running
>   out of file descriptors can be disastrous and will most probably lead
>   to data loss. Make sure to increase the limit on the number of open
>   files descriptors for the user running Elasticsearch to 65,536 or
>   higher.

Therefore you need to increase the limit:

> For the .zip and .tar.gz packages, set **ulimit -n 65535** as root before
>   starting Elasticsearch, or set **nofile** to **65535** in
>   **/etc/security/limits.conf**.

Comment: I did this and still the issue is there

Comment: You executed `ulimit` in the same shell that you use to start Elasticsearch ?

Comment: I set the nofile in /etc/security/limits.cong. Is it OK?

Comment: I don't know how it really works with the limits.conf to be honest. They give 2 solutions, try both !

Comment: I did. But nothing changed. The ulimit -n command gives 65536 as a output

Comment: You still have the same log with [4096] ?

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha Here an extended doc of system settings: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#ulimit

Comment: Should I have to install elasticsearch separately, from installing sonarqube?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198193/discussion-between-arnaud-claudel-and-shehan-dhaleesha).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `fs.file-max` to increase max file descriptors.

> sysctl -w fs.file-max=65535

You're likely to also need to set the `vm.max-map-count`

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: I did it. But it is not the whole answer. You have to change the service file also.